# How to include CSS and javascript file in Google Script App

Tags: javascript, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new about **Google App Script**. I have done coding in google script app. I have read the best practice for adding CSS and JavaScript.
I have followed this documentation and created a JavaScript and CSS file. But when I have run this code, it's showing me wrong output.

Documentaion Link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript

My code is below:

code.gs

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('page')
    .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
    .getContent();
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .createMenu('Dialog')
    .addItem('Open', 'openSidebar')
    .addToUi();
}

function openSidebar() {
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page').setTitle('Dashboard');
```

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput);
}

page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <?!= include('stylesheet'); ?>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>Please enjoy this helpful script.</p>
  <?!= include('javascript'); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

stylesheet.html

```
<style>
  p {
    color: green;
  }
</style>
```

javascript.html

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('Page is loaded');
});
</script>
```

When I click on run with the "opOpen" option it's run success full, but in the out there is nothing any effect. **Its show include line.**

Can anyone teel me where I have done mistake.
[image: Image Output]

Comment: try including them both after `</body>` and add `.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)` to your `include` function

Comment: Now they are displaying like this:

Welcome
Please enjoy this helpful script.

<?!= include('stylesheet'); ?> <?!= include('javascript'); ?>

Comment: function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).getContent()
}

I have added this function, but still the css not applied

Comment: Is there is any other way to include the css and js file?

Comment: I have added the code whatever you have provided but still it not applied css.

Comment: I there is any other way to include the css and js file?

Comment: you included files correctly, but outputting them wrong. Not sure is Sandbox parameters are needed for modal dialog, try first with the example in the answer section.

Answer (score 2):

I'll write the answer here, since it will be better readable.

Your `openDialog` function should look like this

```
function openDialog() {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('page').evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}
```

you also don't need `doGet` for modal dialog or sidebar!

Comment: Thanks a lot sit, it's working fine with dialog.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to apply CSS for sidebar?
For your reference I have modified my question.
I have changed the name of openDoalog to openSidebar and its content also.

Comment: It's exactly the same you use `showSidebar` method instead of `showModalDialog`